# Is Ansible module for Brocade/ICX is misbehaving?

Tags: ansible, brocade, ansible-galaxy

I've to perform some network automation in my infra using Ansible.

When I'm trying to use Ansible module for ICX switches it seems to be misbehaving.

Playbook I used

```yaml
- name: ICX switch testing
  hosts: test-switch
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    ansible_user: username
    ansible_password: password
    ansible_connection=ansible.netcommon.network_cli
    ansible_network_os=icx

  tasks:

    - name: show version
      icx_command:
        commands:
          - show version
```

for this I'm getting below error

```json
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "skip\r\nInvalid input -> skip\r\nType ? for a list\r\nSSH@ICX7250-24P Switch>"}
```

when I use enable mode using Ansible_become then it gives below error

```json
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "unable to elevate privilege to enable mode, at prompt [None] with error: timeout value 60 seconds reached while trying to send command: b'enable'"}
```

I'm not sure why command enable changed to b'enable. Seems some issue with module

ansible version

```bash
ansible 2.9.9
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Sep 26 2019, 11:57:09) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

Answer (score 0):

According the given playbook

```yaml
  vars:
    ansible_user: username
    ansible_password: password
    ansible_connection=ansible.netcommon.network_cli
    ansible_network_os=icx
```

and the error message

```
Invalid input -> skip\r\nType ? for a list
```

there is a typo in `vars:` section as it should be

```yaml
  vars:
    ansible_user: username
    ansible_password: password
    ansible_connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
    ansible_network_os: icx
```

**Further Documentaion**

- [ICX Platform Options](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_icx.html)
- [`icx_command` module – Run arbitrary commands on remote Ruckus ICX 7000 series switches](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/network/icx_command_module.html#ansible-collections-community-network-icx-command-module)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this specific error:

`Invalid input -> skip\r\nType ? for a list`

You may have to modify the actual `icx_config.py` module.

On Macs, for example, it's located here:

`/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/6.4.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible_collections/community/network/plugins/modules/network/icx/icx_config.py`

The line you must modify is, potentially, 364:

`run_commands(module, 'skip')`

Comment it out and try again.

`#run_commands(module, 'skip')`

It took me many days to sort this out after googling with no avail, so maybe it helps someone in the future.